# Creating vectors from a reference vector

Tags: vector-spaces

As in the figure below, I am trying to create a finite number of vectors $v_k$ (blue) around the known reference vector $v_0$ (red). The angle difference between $v_k$ and $v_0$ is denoted by $\theta$, and the magnitude of $v_k$ is $|v_0|$. How can I find those $v_k$? Is there any way that I can parameterize $v_k$ in terms of $v_0$?

[image]

Comment: Do you know about polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to continuously parameterize a $v_k$ purely in terms of $v_0$, unless there is, say, some vector you know $v_0$ will never be. (A consequence of the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem).)

**Step 1:** choose an arbitrary vector $w$ that is not a scalar multiple of $v_0$.  Using the Gram-Schmidt process on $v_0,w$, one can get a unit vector $w'$ that is orthognoal to $v_0$.  Let $w''=(v_0\times w')/\lVert v_0\rVert$.

**Step 2:** now $w',w''$ is a pair of orthogonal unit vectors orthogonal to $v_0$, giving us a coordinate system.  The vector $v_\alpha=\cos(\theta)v_0+\lVert v_0\rVert\sin(\theta)(\cos(\alpha)w'+\sin(\alpha)w'')$ for an angle $\alpha$ is a vector that has the same length as $v_0$, that forms an angle $\theta$ with $v_0$, and that is parameterized by $\alpha$.  Letting $\alpha=2\pi k/n$ for $k=1,\dots,n$ will give $n$ equally spaced vectors $v_k$ around $v_0$.

It's possible that this procedure could be made non-arbitrary at the cost of having the vectors permute as $v_0$ varies.

Answer (score 0):

The $v_k$'s are in a circle. Use co-ordinates. Write $v_0 = (x_0, y_0)^T$ (column vector). For a variable $\theta$ consider the rotation matrix $R_\theta={\cos\theta\quad -\sin\theta \choose \sin\theta \quad \cos\theta}$. Now matrix multiplication $R_\theta v_0$ gives what you want as you vary $\theta$.